# Internet Through USB

Tags: wifi, usb, bluetooth, pi-zero-w, hotspot

Is it possible to get an internet connection for a Rasberry pi zero from a USB connected to a Win 10 pc?

or is it possible to connect to a Bluetooth wifi Hotspot without an OS on a Rasberry Pi Zero?

Comment: Here is a detailed guide explaining the setup for various use cases https://gist.github.com/gbaman/50b6cca61dd1c3f88f41

Comment: Hello, short answer to the first question is "yes": have a search for "Raspberry Pi Zero gadget ethernet".

Comment: In case there's any confusion, the "ethernet gadget" part (which would be USB-OTG on the Pi -> USB on the PC) would what makes it possible for the pi to communicate with the PC directly over USB; you could then arrange for the PC to bridge or forward an internet connection to it.  You can also connect the Zero via USB serial and communicate, but you could not forward an internet connection that way.